# How to host a Minecraft server (not on the same LAN and without using Realms)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends want to play Minecraft together, but they don't want to pay for a Realm. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Ok, I thought they had removed it due to Realms taking over. It can get shut down.

Answer (score 3):

You can run your own server, but you have to do a few things.

1. Download server software from https://minecraft.net/download
2. Port forward. This is a tricky step, so [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router) tutorial will help. If you can't follow it, just search "how to port forward" into google.
3. Find your IP address. If you have a static IP, then it will always remain the same. Chances are, however, that you have a dynamic IP. Two solutions: you either pay your ISP for a static IP, or tell your friends your new IP every time they want to play. To find your IP simply search "What is my IP" into google.
4. If you've done everything correctly, when your friends type your IP address into the direct connect multiplayer box, they should join your server.

Have fun playing!

Comment: You can still download the stuff even though Realms is out?

Comment: @Zorgon Yes, because servers like Mineplex and others still use it. Realms is just for people who want to play together without the hassle of setting up an actual server.

Comment: You can also rent servers or virtual private servers to play minecraft on depending on your preferences this can be as low as $10/month and have a dedicated IP.  Check out Digital Ocean and this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-minecraft-server-on-linux